# Performance on concurrent accesses on a dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a `Dictionary<string,string>` with the following behaviour :

- once a key/value pair is set, the value will never change
- writes are small compared to the reads
- reads and writes may be performed by differents thread

I am currently doing the following. But I was wondering if there is a way to avoid the lock around the TryGet ? I mean I want the best performances for my reads.

```
    private readonly Dictionary<string, string> _mappings = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public string GetValueByKey(string key)
    {
        bool valueFound;
        string value;
        lock (_mappings)
        {
            valueFound = _mappings.TryGetValue(key, out value);
        }

        if (valueFound)
        {
            return value;
        }

        var resolvedValue = ResolveValueForKey(key);
        lock (_mappings)
        {
            _mappings[key] = resolvedValue;//I don't care computing the value and set it several times
            return resolvedValue;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you know about [`ConcurrentDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) ?

Comment: Do you know that you need the best performance? Do you currently have a performance bottleneck with this code?

Comment: @Blorgbeard : No, looking right now

Comment: @Enigmativity : yes I get thousands (up to millions) of calls per seconds and I really see a difference without the lock (but in that case I am also experimenting some exceptions)

Comment: @Toto - I've deleted my confusing answer. If you interested in lock-free code consider reading on  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking instead and all memory barrier and read/write ordering stuff... Using `ConcurrentDictionary` is much easier to reason about if it meets your performance goals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the `ConcurrentDictionary` on this page about [thread-safe collections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Internally, it has a lock for each "bucket" in the hash table. This means that you might get a huge performance boost *if your application has a lot of parallel reads*. Before picking which one to use, you should measure `Dictionary` to see if the performance is acceptable and if it's not, measure `ConcurrentDictionary` to see if you gain performance.